# Exception while Object to xml parsing using jackson

Tags: java, xml, jackson

I am getting below exception while trying to parse my object to xml

Exception:

```
18:10:57,894 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-18) UT005023: Exception handling request  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationConfig.withDefaultPrettyPrinter(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/PrettyPrinter;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/SerializationConfig;
at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper.<init>(XmlMapper.java:86)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper.<init>(XmlMapper.java:67)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper.<init>(XmlMapper.java:49)

.......:46
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:72)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:282)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:80)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:172)
at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:199)
at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:774)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

My code is :

```
XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
String xml = xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(respVO);
```

I am getting this exception on first line(while creating object).

Here is screen shot of my war file:
[image: War file]

Can any one help me here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out problem.
I am running my we application on `wildfly-9.0.1.Final`.
wildfly-9.0.1.Final use modules use `jackson-databind-2.5.1.jar`.
I solved my issue by replacing `jackson-databind-2.5.6.jar` in wildfly module

```
path : 
wildfly-9.0.1.Final\modules\system\layers\base\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\main
```